# Введите максимальное число и количество столбцов для размещения чисел?

Tags: python, консоль

Пользователь вводит число например 23 и вводит кол-во столбцов на которых числа он 1 до 23 должны разместиться
Вот пример, именно в таком формате должны выводится числа если пользователь ввел 3 столбца в консоли[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я сначала решил взять у пользователя эти данные через input также нашел все числа от 1 до числа которое ввел пользователь также подсчитал количество чисел в одном столбце но не уверен что данные которые я нашел нужны
Вот моя очень не правильная попытка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: покажите что вы пробовали делать

Comment: добавьте в вопрос вашу реализацию и вывод в консоль?

Comment: Ок добавил в сообщение

Comment: Код должен быть в виде текста кода, а не картинки.

Answer (score 2):

Вариантов много. Ну, например, такой:

```
import math
mess1=23
mess2=3
lines=math.ceil(mess1/mess2)   
lst=[i for i in range(1,mess1+1)]
for i in range(lines):
    print(*lst[i::lines])
```

Получаем:

```
1 9 17
2 10 18
3 11 19
4 12 20
5 13 21
6 14 22
7 15 23
8 16
```

Comment: выдает ошибки в 6 и 7 строчке

Comment: и можно более простым способом(без math и т.д.)

Comment: @ alex0711 а формат сообщения об ошибке вы не хотите сообщить?

Comment: @ alex0711 -  можно, я же написал "Вариантов много." Можно и без math.ceil, но будет сложнее. Хотите -  напишите.